# What is UILabel default shadowRadius?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, shadow, quartz-core

I use QuartzCore to set UILabel shadows in UITableViewCell:

```
cell.textLabel.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor orange] CGColor];
cell.textLabel.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
cell.textLabel.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
cell.textLabel.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
```

But because of it slow performance, I have to implement `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method.
Recently I found out that shadow for UILabel can be set with it properties:

```
cell.textLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
cell.textLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
```

Now I want delete `drawRect:` implementation and just set shadows through properties.

QuartzCore CALayer `shadowRadius` default value is 3.0.
Though UILabel has not such property, is it mean that shadow radius equauls 0.0?

Comment: For performance sake, try to avoid QuartzCore effects. Use images instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/shadowColor) says:

> Text shadows are drawn with the specified offset and color **and no blurring**.

So, yes, the shadow radius is 0.

Answer (score 2):

just a advise - setting shadow using `QuartzCore` in a `UITableView` cell impacts scroll performance. it would definitely not be smooth scrolling.

I suggest you use a `UIImageView` just below the `UILabel` to give the same effect. Its probably more work to keep the shadow-image updated with changes in design but if its a trade-off between reducing developer effort or improving user-experience; I would incline towards the latter 9 out of 10 times...

Comment: I know about QuartzCore impact to scroll performance. That's why I create subclass of UIView, override its `drawRect:` method, and add this custom view to UITableViewCell contentView.

Comment: how is the scroll perf now?

Comment: It's smooth. But I had to override  drawRect:. When I have searched how implement shadows in UILabel, I only found QuartzCore solution. But it appears that there is better and easy solution. That's why I've asked about shadow radius.